# MacBook doesn't recognize oddly shaped disk

Tags: macbook, optical-drive

I put in a small oddly shaped disk into my MacBook and it didn't recognize it. There was none of the normal sounds you here when a disk is put in, so it doesn't know a disk is in the drive. So I can'tt tell it to eject from *Disk Utility*.

How can I get this disk out?

Comment: I closed the macbook and help it sideways then shook it, and a little bit of the disk came out so I could just pull it out.

Comment: Please post that as an answer then accept it when you can. This helps people note that the question is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, small and odd-sized optical disks only work in certain kinds of tray-loading drives. The slot-loading optical drives on almost all Macs are only designed to work with full-sized 120mm round discs.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2446

There's no way for a slot-loading drive to get a nonstandard disk fully injected and onto the spindle. There's no way to guarantee that the motorized rollers that handle inject and eject will be able to sense it and grip it and do anything with it.

So once you've inserted a nonstandard disk into the slot-loading drive, it's equivalent to having stuck a credit card or guitar pick or some other thin rigid sheet of plastic in there. It's just loose debris in your drive and you have to treat it that way.

Pointing the slot down and shaking it gently hoping it comes out is probably as good as anything. Most technicians would recommend against sticking any tools in there, as you're likely to damage something that way. The only safe bet is time- and hassle-intensive: If you want to protect your warranty, have an authorized technician take the thing apart. Otherwise, take the thing apart yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You might find the following helpful:

http://guides.macrumors.com/Force_Eject_a_Stuck_CD_or_DVD

Comment: That page is years out of date and doesn't cover the case of a slot-loading drive that didn't even power-INject the disc. From his description, his disc may as well have been a loose plastic card in the slot.